# Extract multiple twitter handles in google sheet cell

Tags: regex, google-sheets, spreadsheet

**I'm trying to extract multiple twitter handles in a google sheet, like that :**

```
Lorem Lorem Lorem @Handle1 Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem
Lorem Lorem LoremLorem Lorem Lorem @Handle2 Lorem Lorem Lorem @Handle3
```

**What i want (extracted in the same cell) :**

```
@Handle1
@Handle2
@Handle3
```

How i can do ?

Cheers

Comment: Have a look at [REGEXEXTRACT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098244), a regular expresion like `@\w*` should be the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
@\w+
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/TSnf08/2/).

---

Broken down, this says

```
@\w+      # @-sign + word characters
```

Lookarounds seem not to be supported by `re2` ([**see here for more information**](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax)).

Answer (score 0):

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1, "(@\w*)")&" "&JOIN(" ", REGEXEXTRACT(A1, "(@\w*).*(@\w*)"))
```

[image]

---

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1, "(@\w*)")&CHAR(10)&JOIN(CHAR(10), REGEXEXTRACT(A1, "(@\w*).*(@\w*)"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
=JOIN(CHAR(10), QUERY(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(A1," ")), 
 "select Col1 where Col1 contains '@'", 0))
```

[image]